# Using Accordion inside table element with Razor syntax

Tags: javascript, jquery, model-view-controller, razor

I am attempting to hide/show rows using Accordion. I verified that accordion works on this:

```
<div id="accordion">
   <h3>Some 1:</h3>
      <div><p>ABC</p></div>
   <h3>Some 2:</h3>
      <div><p>Muris</p></div>
</div>
```

But when attempting to use it for my application, it's not working. Below is what I'm trying to accomplish. I'm not sure if it's the placement of some of the tags, simply accordion does not work within a table element, or the razor syntax is an issue.

```
<table>
<tr>
    <th>Name</th>
    <td>@Html.Display("Name")</td>
</tr>
<tr>
    <th>Event</th>
    <th>Program</th>
</tr>
<div id="accordion">
 @for (var i = 0; i < @ViewBag.Events.Count; i++)
{
<tr>
    <td><h3>@ViewBag.Events[i].Event</h3></td>
    <td>@ViewBag.Events[i].Program</td>
</tr>
@Html.Raw("<div>")
<tr>
    <td>Value A</td>
    <td>Value B</td>
</tr>
for (var j = 0; j < @ViewBag.Events[i].Azc.Count; j++)
{
<tr>
    <td>@ViewBag.Events[i].Azc[j].ValueA</td>
    <td>@ViewBag.Events[i].Azc[j].ValueB</td>
</tr>
}
@Html.Raw("</div>")
}
</div>
```

So basically, I want all the Event/Programs to be visible as rows, and upon clicking one of the rows, the rest of the rows for that Event are shown.

Comment: Your creating invalid html (`<div>` is not a valid child of a `<table>` element) so it won't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are right. Accordion does not work within a table element. You can do this by using jquery-accordion along with bootstrap grid system: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Comment: Good enough for me to know and try another approach. Thanks.